# JS/Regex: Remove a substring from end of string with optional comma and spaces in front and dot behind

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to remove the string `et al` from the end of a string using a regex. Optional there could be a dot at the end and there could be a comma and/or multiple spaces in front of this substring:

https://regex101.com/r/aBw7xy/1

```
string.replace(/.*(,\s?\s*et\s+al.*)$/g, '')
```

But this is not working for the first line of these input examples:

```
name firstname secondname et al
name firstname secondname, et al
name firstname secondname,et al
name firstname secondname, et al.
name     firstname     secondname,   et   al.
name firstn. sec., et al.
name f s, et al.
```

I want to get rid of each `et al` and space/comma in front of this substring.

Result should be:

```
name firstname secondname
name firstname secondname
name firstname secondname
name firstname secondname
name     firstname     secondname
name firstn. sec.
name f s
```

How do I test first, if there is a match for the group at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one :

```
(,?\s*et\s+al.*)$
```

yours : .*(,\s?\s*et\s+al.*)$
.* will match all you wish keep,
\s? do not need any more, since yo have a \s*